# change CSS then Load HTML file not Working

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

This is probably hard to answer. I use jQuery to manipulate the styling of text in a div. Things work fine. Then I use jQuery Ajax load, to load new text, and replace the old. I expected the modified CSS to stick, but it is not. It is reverting to the unmodified CSS. Does that make sense?

Comment: How are you modifying the CSS?

Comment: It's a new element. You need to apply the styling again as part of Ajax callback.

Comment: Show some code. If you're using `.css(...)`, that just puts inline style attributes on the DOM elements, which you are then replacing wholesale. So of course those attributes are lost.

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit vague. Please add the code to make it clearer.

Here is the fiddle in which I have tried to demonstrate a solution for the problem I understood.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">
<div class="testblock">
    <div class="test">
        Test One
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        Test Two
    </div>
</div>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
.red_div {
    color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.test').addClass('red_div');

    $("form[ajax=true]").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var form_url = $(this).attr("action");
        var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase();

        $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            cache: false,
            success: function(){                          
                new_div = $('.testblock')
                            .append('<div class="test">Test Three</div>');
                //new_div.addClass('red_div');

            }           
        });    

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dUsf/

Comment: Close. In my case, I did not add a class, but I modified an existing class. With this: $('.sen').css({'width': '50%'}); When Ajax brought new text that uses this same class, the modified class was not used by the browser, so I had to style it again. I am trying to avoid restyling, because my document is very big and it takes too long.

Comment: Style only those changed elements. See in the above example, only the new_div is restyled.